# Terminal Services: 2nd concurrent user causes deployed .NET application instance to crash

Tags: .net, service, concurrency, terminal, rdp

Here are the fact patterns I'm trying to troubleshoot:

An application whose client (WinForms) and server (WCF Soap) components are deployed to the same Terminal Server.

There are two users trying to access the desktop app remotely via RDP. This app relies entirely on connection to the SOAP server -- no direct SQL Server access.

When the second user logs in at a time the first user is running the desktop application in their RDP session, his instance of the desktop application immediately crashes. Windows offers to find a solution to the problem, but apparently turns nothing up.

The first user's session is unperturbed by the failure, and works as expected.

When both users are admins, curiously, both can access the application concurrently in their respective sessions.

I'm not a systems admin and this smells like a configuration problem. Any thoughts about what the root cause might be, and how we can further troubleshoot the issue, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  The first thing I'd look at is if the program is writing to a fixed location on disk.  That would create a conflict.  The other thing I'd try to find is where the crash is occuring...you may have to screw around with remote debugging to accomplish that.

Comment: I did not code the app and at present do not have access to the source. My first thought was that perhaps there is a lock on some shared resource being accessed by an application singleton, but the developer assures me that this is done on a per-user basis.